# Oracle adf table

Tags: oracle-adf

How to fetch the oracle adf table values at managed bean programmatically.
I have used the create insert operation for creating row. After saving the value I am not able to fetch the value of row using iterator. Can someone please tell me why iterator is coming empty.
I have tried to getting value using vo impl but I am not getting values there also.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify where are you looking to iterate? In the view layer or the model layer? Is your code in a managed bean or in the ADF BC methods?
Some basics here:
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/ADF_Insider_Essentials/IterateRows/IterateRows.html